# async being called before I am planning on it being called

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I am struggling with a current feature of my code. I am attempting to upload a set of data to both the local SQL database I have created and to firebase at one time. They both hold the same exact strings. For some reason when I upload to firebase the string values have values and upload no problem. The same exact strings going into the database however are coming through as null.

When I press the submit button this `validateAndSubmit()` method is called

```
void validateAndSubmit() async {
    setState(() {
      _errorMessage = "";
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    print("Auth: " + widget.auth.getUserId());

    if (validateAndSave()) {
      try {
        String _uid = widget.auth.getUserId();
        uploadImage(imageToUpload: _image, title: _uid + "_profile_pic");
        final databaseReference = Firestore.instance;
        print("name: " + _nameF);

        await  _save(NewUser(1,_nameF,_nameL,_age, _grad,_highschool,_state,_city,_heightFeet,_heightInch,_weight,_hand,_position,_club,'PL'));

        await databaseReference.collection("users").document(_uid).setData({
          'nameF': _nameF,
          'nameL': _nameL,
          'age': _age,
          'grade': _grad,
          'highschool': _highschool,
          'state': _state,
          'city': _city,
          'heightFeet': _heightFeet,
          'heightInch': _heightInch,
          'weight': _weight,
          'hand': _hand,
          'position': _position,
          'club': _club,
          'type': 'PL',
        });

        await databaseReference.collection("players").document(_uid).setData({
          'Type': "Player",
        });


        Navigator.push(
          context,
          new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new HomePage(
            userId: _uid, auth: widget.auth, logoutCallback: null,)),
        );
      }
      catch (e) {
        print(e.message);
      }
    }
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }
```

When I call the await to upload firebase, it uploads as expected. when I call `_save` I the values of all the strings come through as null. I have tried even adding a print statement before the `_save` and the value of the string is null. Is there any reason they would be called at different times?

Here is the code for `_save:`

```
_save(NewUser user) async {
  DatabaseHelper helper = DatabaseHelper.instance;
  print(user.toString());
  int id = await helper.insertUser(user);
  print('inserted row: $id');
}
```

Comment: `await` yields execution.  Other code could execute in the meantime and modify your `_nameF`, `_nameL`, et. al. members.  You either should prevent mutating your object while you're waiting for the asynchronous operations to complete, or you should save local copies first.

Comment: I think my confusion here then, would be that I am expecting those values to change onPressed of a button. Is there anyway that you know to ensure the values of the strings have been gotten from the onPressed method prior to this await executing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing the code and doing some tweaks/ thinking about @jamesdlin said, I noticed that the database initialization was the only piece required to be asynchronous. I then separated the init statement for the database into a method separate from the insert and changed the insert into a raw insert. I found success with this method. Thank you!

```
_save()  {

    database.rawInsert('INSERT INTO user(name, age) VALUES(?, ?, ?,?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?, ?,? , ?, ?)', [_nameF,_nameL,_age, _grad,_highschool,_state,_city,_heightFeet,_heightInch,_weight,_hand,_position,_club,'PL']);
  }

  _intiDatabase() async{
    database = await DatabaseHelper.instance.database;
  }
```

This was the code I used as s solution.